# Are the diagonals of the density operator always the probabilities of finding the system in various states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, density-operator

I found lecture notes online that said "Diagonal density matrix elements are the probabilities of finding system in various states." My quantum mechanics textbook doesn't say anything about this, it just says that the probability a state is in $\big|\phi \big>$ can be found from the density operator $\hat \rho=\big|\psi\big>\big<\psi\big|$ by using the projection operator $\hat P_{|\phi>}=\big|\phi\big>\big<\phi\big|$ and taking the trace of the product of the two operators:

$$tr\big(\hat P_{|\phi>}\hat \rho\big)=\big<\phi|\psi \big> \big<\psi|\phi\big>= \big|\big<\phi|\psi \big> \big|^2.$$

I can see that this is the probability, and from what I understand this will always work. However, it seems like just using the diagonal elements is much faster than having to do this math. Is it safe to say that the diagonal elements of the density matrix itself will always give you the probabilities or does it depend on the basis that the matrix is in?

Comment: What if the state you're interested in doesn't form part of the basis you're working with?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty In that case it's not possible to use the diagonals to find the probability. Is that why the method the book provided is more useful?